# How to display images from dropbox in UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, dropbox

I am using [**DBChooser**](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/ios) in my application to import images from dropbox, I am getting image url [like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qey2let40eb9je/PRELIMINARY_FORM_2.jpg) & to dasplay the image in UIImageView i have following code

```
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qey2let40eb9je/PRELIMINARY_FORM_2.jpg"]]];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

but the image is not showing in application. please help me how to display the dropbox image in UIImageView, is it issue of **https** OR what .

Comment: Such an image will take time to load. Use an NSURLConnection to get the image data

Comment: You should load image which downloaded from web in background thread. Should check download successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

See this reference: https://cantonbecker.com/etcetera/2014/how-to-directly-link-or-embed-dropbox-images/

Short answer: append raw=1 as querystring value to your image url

Answer (score -1):

Let's try:

```
+ (void) downloadImage : (NSURL*) url withCallBack:(DownloadCallbackBlock)callback
{
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpresponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if (httpresponse.statusCode == 200)
    {
        callback(error,data);
    }
    else
    {
        //error
    }
}];
}
```

And I use it:

```
[DownloadManager downloadImage:url withCallBack:^(NSError *error, NSData *data){
                                    if (data)
                                    {
                                        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
                                        [_arrImages addObject:image];
                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                            [self processAddImage];

                                        });
                                    }
```